# nHibernate object mappings create key violations

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent

Got a bit of an odd situation which I'm trying to map in Fluent nHibernate and failing. I have an Asset object which contains both an Image object and a File object. The Id of Image and File is identical, and the Image object contains a File object. This situation arises because an Image is always also a File (which is why the Id's have to match) but a File is not always an image.

I've mapped this as follows:

AssetMap

```
Public Sub New()
    Id(Function(x) x.Id)
    Map(Function(x) x.DisplayOrder)
    Map(Function(x) x.Text).Length(10000)
    Map(Function(x) x.Title)
    Map(Function(x) x.Width)
    Map(Function(x) x.Height)
    References(Function(x) x.Image).LazyLoad().Cascade.All()
    References(Function(x) x.File).LazyLoad().Cascade.All()
    References(Function(x) x.Row).Cascade().All()
    Map(Function(x) x.AssetType).CustomType(Of AssetType)()
End Sub
```

ImageMap

```
Public Sub New()
    Id(Function(x) x.ID)
    Map(Function(x) x.Height)
    Map(Function(x) x.Width)
    Map(Function(x) x.AltText)
    Map(Function(x) x.ToolTip)
    Map(Function(x) x.ImageStatus).CustomType(Of ImageStatus)()
    References(Function(x) x.Product).Nullable()
    HasOne(Function(x) x.File).Constrained()
    References(Function(x) x.ViewTag)
    HasManyToMany(Function(x As Image) x.ProductOptionValues).Table("ImageVsProductOptionValues").LazyLoad().Cascade.All()
    HasManyToMany(Function(x As Image) x.MappedCategories).Table("CategoryVsImage").LazyLoad().Cascade.All().Inverse()
End Sub
```

Filemap

```
Public Sub New()
    Id(Function(x) x.Id)
    Map(Function(x) x.Data).LazyLoad().Length(Integer.MaxValue)
    Map(Function(x) x.MimeType)
    Map(Function(x) x.Size)
    Map(Function(x) x.Filename)
    Map(Function(x) x.LastDateModified)
    Map(Function(x) x.DateCreated)
End Sub
```

I've run into trouble trying to use the following code to create a new image and add it to an Asset and save it.

```
        If oAsset.Image Is Nothing Then
            currentImage = New CMS.DataTransferObjects.Image
            currentFile = New CMS.DataTransferObjects.File
        Else
            currentImage = oAsset.Image
            currentFile = oAsset.File
        End If

        currentFile.Data = ms.ToArray
        currentFile.MimeType = mimeType
        currentFile.Filename = filImgUpload.FileName
        currentFile.Size = filImgUpload.ContentLength
        currentImage.Width = CInt(Utils.Convert.ToInt64(UploadedImage.PhysicalDimension.Width))
        currentImage.Height = CInt(Utils.Convert.ToInt64(UploadedImage.PhysicalDimension.Height))

        If oAsset.Image Is Nothing Then
            oAsset.Image = currentImage
            oAsset.File = currentFile
        Else
            'currentImage = oAsset.Image
            'currentFile = oAsset.File
        End If
```

I then call an nHibernate manager and try up .Update the Asset, which results in the following error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK30EBACDFED57EBE9". The conflict occurred in database "BDM1_TestBed", table "dbo.File", column 'Id'.
```

Can anyone help sort out this mess - I assume my mappings are wrong, but I'm not sure how to improve them?

Answer (score 0):

Before I post my thoughts, I'd reccomend NHibernate Profiler, if you're not using it already. It's saved my butt countless times with mapping issues, and there's a free trial if you want to just try it out. Usually, in a situation like this, seeing the SQL generated by NHIbernate (via NHProf) has led me to the solution. Check it out here: http://www.nhprof.com/

As for my thoughts, It does look like your mapping is incomplete. Try adding ForeignKey to your AssetMap, like so:

```
References(Function(x) x.File)
    .ForeignKey("Id")
    .LazyLoad()
    .Cascade.All()
```

You will probably need to do the same for the ImageMap

From what I recall, Fluent NHibernate will automatically use the convention "Tablename_Id" if you don't specify the name explicitly.

Hope that helps. Let me know if that doesn't do it.